# The MLP library on sklearn

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, scikit-learn

I have been using the mlp library on the sklearn on some unsupervised data. I have been getting training set scores between 0.7 - 0.9 .However my test set scores have been really low. I assume this is due to over fitting and have read and understood that regularization (to help smooth weight/bias) and early stopping would help prevent this issue. However I am finding it hard to implement it, could someone help me with an implementation or guide me on the right path with a suitable link.

(The tutorial on regularization for clf on sklearn did not really help me as I found it to be confusing with little explanation)

Comment: Add your codes...

Comment: do you mean supervised?

Comment: The dataset is unsupervised...

Comment: and you're using the scikit-learn MLPClassifier? how does that go together?